# css class applied only on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

on every 2 sec my js function is fired and after certain logic I want to apply css class with effect on html element on the page.

```
   var myCounter= 0;        

    $interval(function () {            
        myCounter++;
        DoSomething();
        $('#myElem_' + myCounter).addClass('myClass');
    }, 2000);

    function DoSomething() {
        if (myCounter<= 35) {                
            if (myCounter == 0) {
                $scope.myIndex= 1;
            } else {
                $scope.myIndex= myCounter;                   
            }

        } else {
            // not implemented
        }
    }
```

on html page css class is applied only first time. Counter works but css can be applied on first element only.

on html page there are unique id numbers on html elements, like

```
<div id="myElem_1"></div>
<div id="myElem_2"></div>
```

Comment: can you share somewhere

Comment: Create a demo on jsfiddle or plnkr or share the complete code

Comment: Code seems fine. Consider using `angular.element()` instead of jQuery ^^

Comment: I guess there is some logical error in the `DoSomething()`, not sure what is

Comment: if these elements are already present in the html page, why cant use jquery function to select all div`s start with div[id^="myElem_"] and apply css on one shot.

Comment: working http://plnkr.co/edit/8yn2DbLhm0TwczMAqWni?p=preview

Comment: what problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems perfectly fine. Do note that the first element gets the class after 2 seconds and then after **another** 2 seconds the 2nd element gets the class.

So you'd have to wait a total of **4 seconds** to see everything change.

Comment: `on html page css class is applied only first time. Counter works but css can be applied on first element only.`

Comment: Er... I seem to be reading the question wrongly then. OPs problem is not that the 2nd element is not getting the class at all or the 2nd element is not getting the class AFTER the first time? Btw here's the fiddle I had http://jsfiddle.net/dr85a2u6/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$scope.$apply();` in your function after all the changes:

```
function DoSomething() {
    if (myCounter<= 35) {                
        if (myCounter == 0) {
            $scope.myIndex= 1;
        } else {
            $scope.myIndex= myCounter;                   
        }

    } else {
        // not implemented
    }

    $scope.$apply(); // <---put this one here.

}
```

I guess you are changing/updating some scope variables in the function above so you need to tell angular to check for changes and update the scope.

Comment: I don't think `apply()` is needed. `$('#myElem_' + myCounter).addClass('myClass');` should do it. Still we don't know what is `myIndex`, your solution might be correct depending on `myIndex`, if it is used for classes.

Comment: `$scope.myIndex= myCounter;` when this line updates in the scope angular doesn't know about it so this should have to be done.

Comment: Yeah, I know, as `$interval` is executing asynchronously executing, it is required to force the changes. But, as I said above, is this really required in this context just to add class

Comment: @Tushar seems althogh it is getting executed but it is not updating the current scope object vars.

Comment: @Jai I tried with $scope.apply() but I've got $scope.apply is not a function. Then I tried with $scope.$apply() but now I have error in firebug Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: @user1765862 whoops!! my mistake its `$scope.$apply();` missed the `$` from the `apply`.

Comment: @Jai yes but I still got an error,  Error: [$rootScope:inprog]